# DependencyResolver - How to get a named registration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity 3 in an MVC 5 app. I have registered 2 named registrations as follows:

```
container
    .RegisterType<IService, Service>(
          "n1", 
          new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), 
          new InjectionConstructor("n1"))

    .RegisterType<IService, Service>(
          "n2", 
          new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), 
          new InjectionConstructor("n2")));
```

Now I am struggling to get those back. The `IDependencyResolver` doesn't have a `GetService<T>()` which accepts a name.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    RegisterTypes(container);
    return container;
});

public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
{
    return container.Value;
}
```

and then try to get as shown below

```
var service = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<IService>("n1");
```